# Server with JSP and android application

Tags: android, jsp, web

I'd like to create website using java jsp.
The problem is I also want to have an android application instead of a mobile version.
I have no problems with the server part, but I worked on only 2 android apps, and I have no ideas how the apps works when they are created to replace the mobile website.

Is it possible to "connect" the application to the JSP?

If not, the best solution I think about would be to recreate the UI on android and add sockets or webservices to perform the same operations from the app.

I guess there is a simple solution due to the number of android apps doing this, but I don't know it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by connect, but, an app may internally use a webview. You will still likely need to recreate the ui as a desktop ui is inappropriate for a phone.  Keep in mind using JSP based servlets is considered obselete in favor of JSF or a modern web framework like spring.

Comment: By connect, I meant retrieve the JSP content to display it on the app.
I know JSP are obsolete, I just never used JSF yet so i'll use JSF but said JSP because it's easier to explain a problem with a technology I already know. 
I was thinking about trying spring maybe I will